# food-writing tag

Tags: discussion, tags

After a discussion with Monica in the comments of this question:
[Injecting creativity into a cookbook](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42760/injecting-creativity-into-a-cookbook#42760)

We have added a tag for [food-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-writing)

Wiki:

> Use this tag for questions within the genre of food writing.
>   Food-related blogs and books, cookbooks, scripts for cooking videos,
>   podcasts, or TV, food-related travel writing, restaurant reviews,
>   blogs and websites about food, cooking, or eating. Can also be used
>   for questions focusing on food research and description within
>   fiction.

I looked for other questions to add the tag to and only found one.  Which surprises me since this is a huge genre in nonfiction and very popular not just for bloggers but also short video makers, newspaper writers, and magazines.

Question: You all cool with this?  Any changes you want to make?

Comment: I'll just have to come up with some more questions to add to it.

Comment: I've been casually blogging my CSA and some resulting meals all winter, but it never occurred to me to either polish it or ask questions here about it.  Good idea.

Comment: @MonicaCellio having a tag encourages people to ask questions about it. :)

Answer (score 6):

**We shouldn't be afraid to make changes as the need arises.**

Sometimes, the need for a tag crops up. Often, it's a single question that gets things started, *but* as long as we can see a reasonable number of on-topic questions benefiting from the tag for categorization, there's a good chance it's a good tag. I think [food-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-writing) meets that criteria.

The same goes for the tag wiki excerpt; provide some guidance for the tag's usage, but if it turns out to be unclear, or too narrow, or too broad, or whatever, nothing says we can't change it.

**Very little on the site is cast in stone.**

Tags, and tag wikis, and tag wiki excerpts, are editable [just like questions and answers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/editing), and for good reason. The reputation limits are different, but the basic concept remains the same: collaborative editing ultimately improves the quality of the content.

Comment: I agree except I also see a lot of people creating tags on their questions that shouldn't be there at all.  Sometimes they're misspellings or alternate versions of existing tags.  Sometimes they're tags that need discussion first and will be turned down.  For example, I saw a need for a [library] tag but I asked on Meta first and people said no, so I didn't create it.  We've got a *lot* of tags with just one question on them.

Comment: @Cyn True; but those cases can and should be edited. Just because someone adds a tag doesn't mean it's the right tag; but just because someone doesn't know of a tag doesn't mean the idea behind the edit isn't a good one. Again, collaborative editing is supposed to improve the quality of the content, even when the "content" is just a list of categorization blurbs called "tags".

Answer (score 0):

I'm all for it

For the sake of discussion, is there maybe a larger group here that can be lumped together?

Possibly similar topics:

- Travel
- Lifestyle

(please edit if you know what this group would be called or have more suggestions)

Comment: While I think travel-writing is a very reasonable tag to add at whatever point we first need it, I absolutely do not want to see food and travel lumped together (though sometimes they overlap).  Lifestyle also doesn't fit because it's a newspaper category that sometimes (not always) runs food and travel and entertainment articles too.  It's also a genre of nonfiction but there it's about vague improving your life stuff, or look at famous me stuff, which can sometimes include food.

Comment: Yeah "self-help" was also sort of floating around in there – if it's not obvious to us designing a tag it won't be obvious to users trying to guess its purpose…. **"Look at famous me"** –– omg that is so on the nose. Ha!